# Clustered index rebuild appears to do nothing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a clustered index, which shows ~70% fragmentation on a SQL Server 2008 database. I'm trying to rebuild this index:

`ALTER INDEX PK_Table1Index ON Table1 REBUILD`

The statement returns immediately with success, however the fragmentation is not changing. If I review the fragmentation in the SSMS, it remains the same.

I'm suspicious that it returns immediately, so it seems as if it's not doing anything. Since a clustered index determines the table layout on disk, I'd assume that this would have to be an offline task?

I guess I'm missing something and was hoping somebody could shed some light.

Comment: How big is the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is the table?

A small table that is only a few pages/extents rows will always show high fragmentation

Comment: This particular table is 199 rows. Data space: 0.023Mb, Index space: 0.016Mb. So yes, it's pretty small. So you are saying there is no way to improve that, and it doesn't matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter. This 5 8k database pages and fragmentation is measured over extents (simply) which is 8 x8 8k pages. Normally these tables should be filtered out. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5365/630

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. For some reason I thought that the tables were larger, but so far they are all small.